# Get the ID of the trigger object in MarketingCloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

We built a triggered-send in the SalesCloud via the Marketing Cloud Connector. The trigger listens on a custom object (ReferenceCall) which relates to a lead object. If the trigger fires we send an email via marketing cloud. But in this email we need data from the trigger object (ReferenceCall).

One lead can have several ReferenceCall objects, so I cannot clearly get the right object via AMPScript and the lead-id. I need the ID of the object which triggered the send in MarketingCloud too. Is it possibile to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using Salesforce Data Events from within Journey Builder, rather than using a triggered send directly from CRM.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/

The Event creates a Flow in CRM that can pass data relating to the triggering object (ReferenceCall) and other related data as part of the Entry Event Data to Journey Builder. I'd be very careful when switching these on - particularly if you're using Person Accounts in SFDC as they can conflict with other flows, triggers, workflows or processes. So keep a close eye on the logs to make sure the SFMC flow isn't blocking other important processes withing CRM and be prepared to deactivate the flow if you see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround. I added a custom field in the lead object and stored the trigger object (RefCall) in this field. The field is only used for this single transaction. After that I could query this field via AMPscript and get the needed data from the Ref-Call Object.

It's not the best way, but for me it fits.